# Mechanization of Mathematics

Tags: automated-theorem-proving, resolution

Its been a while since I took my theory course, but I recall that Hilberts Decision problem was shown to be false.

> By the completeness theorem of first-order logic, a statement is universally valid if and only if it can be deduced from the axioms, so the Entscheidungsproblem can also be viewed as asking for an **algorithm to decide whether a given statement is provable from the axioms using the rules of logic.**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem).

But In my AI course, we learned of an algorithm to prove or disprove new statements using the axioms known as [Resolution by refutation](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~logicp/unification-resolution/resolution-refutation.html). Simply take the a negation of the statement you want to prove, and use the axioms to show it either leads to an empty clause (true) or non-empty clause (false).

So my question is: What am I missing from these two seemingly contradictory statements? On one hand the literature states there exists no algorithm to determine if a statement is provable from the axioms, and on the other hand, I am presented with an algorithm that proves (or disproves) a statement from the axioms. What am I confused or incorrect about here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing what resolution refutation works for -- namely, just [*propositional* logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus).

For example, try using that algorithm on "There exist integers x, y, z such that ​x<sup>3</sup> + y<sup>3</sup> + z<sup>3</sup> ​= ​33."

There are sets of axioms for which the set of theorems is decidable -- the [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) axioms are the most important example of that, and they in fact also allow quantifier elimination.

There are sets of axioms for which the set of theorems is *not* decidable -- by [undecidability](https://naughtybag.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/jonesmatijasevic.pdf) of [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation), all [Σ<sub>1</sub>-sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#Definition) extensions of [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) are examples of that.